# Proper way to use <> with multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When using <> or =! to exclude mulitple values for a report is the correct format between the different values "OR"? I figured that using the table the value is from between the two would help but I seem to still be pulling in values for discontinued items. I tried two different configurations with the same results

example:

```
o.OrderStatusCode <> ('DISC') OR o.OrderStatusCode <> ('CANC')
```

I tried this configuration also

```
o.orderstatusCode <> ('DISC', 'CANC")
```

neither of them gave me the results needed- DISC values still showed on the report. Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want `o.orderstatusCode NOT IN ('DISC', 'CANC")`

Comment: `o.OrderStatusCode <> ('DISC') OR o.OrderStatusCode <> ('CANC')` will be true for all non-null OrderStatusCode values. Try `o.OrderStatusCode <> ('DISC') AND o.OrderStatusCode <> ('CANC')` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You want `not in`:

```
o.orderstatusCode not in ('DISC', 'CANC')
```

However, the logical equivalent with `<>` uses `AND`, not `OR`:

```
o.orderstatusCode <> 'DISC' and o.orderstatusCode <> 'CANC'
```

Otherwise, your code always evaluates to `TRUE` (or `NULL`) because one of the conditions is always true -- if the code is `'DISC'` then the logic is `FALSE OR TRUE`.